# Trying to understand "no less so but no more so," I've got nowhere

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've been trying to understand the phrase “no less so but no more so” in the context below, does this mean “although she was sometimes alone, sometimes not”?

This kind of comparative structure in English or rhetoric is hard for me to understand, so can you rephrase the “no less so but no more so”?

> This city had become a home to her. She was alone in it, but as alone in it as she had been everywhere in her life ------ no less so but no more so ------ and at least here it was a place she’d chosen. (Taken from  *Heat of Lies*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the quoted passage

> no less but no more so

means

> equal to.

*No more so* in the context given means *no greater than.* In other words, *no less than and no more than.*

She was alone in the city, but she had been equally alone everywhere else.

The writer seems to want to emphasize this equality, and so says it in a somewhat elaborate way, and in a way that places the information about this equality later in the sentence. Whether it was a good or bad writing choice is a matter of opinion, of course.